# Replace values in column based on column header

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to replace values in a column in columns that contain a certain value. So far I have two queries that work independently but now I'm trying to have them work together. Tried a lot of things to integrate them but no luck so far. Thanks!

```
Sub FindAddressColumn()
  Dim rngAddress As Range
  Set rngAddress = Range("A1:Z1").Find("Location")
  If rngAddress Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Address column was not found."
    Exit Sub
  End If
  Range(rngAddress, rngAddress.End(xlDown)).Select
End Sub

Sub findrep()
    Dim i As String
    Dim k As String
    i = "1"
    k = "2"
    Columns("B").Replace what:=i, replacement:=k, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
Sub findrep()
    Dim i As String
    Dim k As String
    Dim rngAddress As Range
    i = "1"
    k = "2"

    Set rngAddress = Range("A1:Z1").Find("Location")
    If rngAddress Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox "Address column was not found."
      Exit Sub
    End If
    Range(rngAddress, rngAddress.End(xlDown)).Replace what:=i, replacement:=k, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: I will dive into how you did it exactly but for now it works like a charm, thanks a lot!